# Request Module returning null for google API

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I was trying Gmail APIs. Using POSTMAN I have created oAuth 2.0 token and was able to hit the URL `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xyz@gmail.com/profile`. But when I was trying same with my node project where I invoked the same using :

`app.get('/getMail',getMail);` in my `index.js` where `getMail` is as follows

```
exports.getMail =  (req, res) => {

request({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xyz@gmail.com/profile",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer token'
  },
  json: true
}, function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  return res.json(response);
});
```

But I am getting the response as null. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the callback function to include `error`. The callbacks are usually error-first callbacks meaning first argument is always error.

```
exports.getMail =  (req, res) => {

request({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xyz@gmail.com/profile",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer token'
  },
  json: true
   // Here -> error
}, function(error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error); // Handle the error here.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  return res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: Perfect :) I am not able to access the answer within 11 min. But I will do the same.